# How to uppercase acronyms in a dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace

I have a dataframe `df` which contains company names that I need to neatly-format. The names are already in titlecase:

```
      Company Name     
0         Visa Inc    
1         Msci Inc
2    Coca Cola Inc
3         Pnc Bank
4         Aig Corp
5    Td Ameritrade 
6         Uber Inc
7       Costco Inc
8   New York Times
```

Since many of the companies go by an acronym or an abbreviation (rows `1`, `3`, `4`, `5`), I want only the first string in those company names to be uppercase, like so:

```
      Company Name     
0         Visa Inc    
1         MSCI Inc
2    Coca Cola Inc
3         PNC Bank
4         AIG Corp
5    TD Ameritrade 
6         Uber Inc
7       Costco Inc
8   New York Times
```

I know I can't get 100% accurate replacement, but I believe I can get close by uppercasing only the first string if:

- it's 4 or fewer characters
- and the first string is not a word in the dictionary

How can I achieve this with something like: `df['Company Name'] = df['Company Name'].replace()`?

Comment: This is not very easy honestly, because if you would try to do these by hand for example. What would your logic be?

Comment: Yeah I know it won't be perfect, but I think I can get ~80% there by using a combination of the above rules. The rest I can just clean manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution, which makes use of a english word list. Only it's not accurate for `td` and `uber`, but like you said, this will be hard to get 100% accurate.

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_alpha.txt'

words = set(pd.read_csv(url, header=None)[0])

w1 = df['Company Name'].str.split()
m1 = ~w1.str[0].str.lower().isin(words) # is not an english word
m2 = w1.str[0].str.len().le(4) # first word is < 4 characters

df.loc[m1 & m2, 'Company Name'] = w1.str[0].str.upper() + ' ' + w1.str[1:].str.join(' ')

     Company Name
0        Visa Inc
1        MSCI Inc
2   Coca Cola Inc
3        PNC Bank
4        AIG Corp
5   Td Ameritrade
6        UBER Inc
7      Costco Inc
8  New York Times
```

**Note**: I also tried this with `nltk` package, but apparently, the `nltk.corpus.words` module is by far not complete with the english words.

Comment: But isn't Uber a word (merriam-webster.com/dictionary/über-)? Also, why wouldn't `TD` be capitalized since it's not a word.

Comment: It's not perfect, like you said, this is never perfect solvable. This should work for 80% as you aimed for.

Comment: Yeah I think this gets me the closest. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

So you can actually use the enchant module to find out if it is a dictionary word or not. Given you are still going to have some off results I.E. Uber.

Here is the code I came up with, sorry for the terrible names of variables and what not.

```
import enchant
import pandas as pd


def main():
    d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
    listofcompanys = ['Msci Inc',
                      'Coca Cola Inc',
                      'Pnc Bank',
                      'Aig Corp',
                      'Td Ameritrade',
                      'Uber Inc',
                      'Costco Inc',
                      'New York Times']

    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(listofcompanys, columns=['Company Name'])
    for index, name in dataframe.iterrows():
        first_word = name['Company Name'].split()
        is_word = d.check(first_word[0])
        if not is_word:
            name['Company Name'] = first_word[0].upper() + ' ' + first_word[1]

    print(dataframe)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output for this was:

```
         Company Name
0        MSCI Inc
1   Coca Cola Inc
2        PNC Bank
3        AIG Corp
4   TD Ameritrade
5        UBER Inc
6      Costco Inc
7  New York Times
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first separate the first words and the other parts. Then filter those first words based on your logic:

```
company_list = ['Visa']

s = df['Company Name'].str.extract('^(\S+)(.*)')

mask = s[0].str.len().le(4) & (~s[0].isin(company_list))
df['Company Name'] = s[0].mask(mask, s[0].str.upper()) + s[1]
```

Output (notice that `NEW` in `New York` gets changed as well):

```
     Company Name
0        Visa Inc
1        MSCI Inc
2   COCA Cola Inc
3        PNC Bank
4        AIG Corp
5   TD Ameritrade
6        UBER Inc
7      Costco Inc
8  NEW York Times
```

Comment: I won't have an existing company list to compare to though. Which is why I think excluding words already in the dictionary, and ones that are beyond a certain length might be a better approach.

Comment: You can certainly pass the word dictionary to `isin` instead of `company_list`. I just put it there as an example.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you first word from the string and make it upper only for those company names that are included in the `include` list:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

company_name = {'Visa Inc', 'Msci Inc', 'Coca Cola Ins', 'Pnc Bank'}

include = ['Msci', 'Pnc']

df = pd.DataFrame(company_name)
df.rename(columns={0: 'Company Name'}, inplace=True)

df['Company Name'] = df['Company Name'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0].upper() + ' ' + x[len(x.split()[0].upper()):] if x.split()[0].strip() in include else x)


df['Company Name']
```

Output:

```
0        MSCI  Inc
1    Coca Cola Ins
2        PNC  Bank
3         Visa Inc
Name: Company Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: This won't work because it's capitalizing words that shouldn't be (e.g., Visa and Coca). Both those are actual words in the dictionary though, hence why I suggested the rule about not uppercasing dictionary words.

Comment: @MSD now it works the way you suggest, but there's the overhead of first creating a list with abbreviations you want to capitalize

Comment: Yeah I need to avoid that because I won't know the abbreviations in advance

Answer (score 0):

A manual workaround could be appending words like "uber"

```
from nltk.corpus import words

dict_words = words.words()
dict_words.append('uber')
```

create a new column

```
df.apply(lambda x : x['Company Name'].replace(x['Company Name'].split(" ")[0].strip(), x['Company Name'].split(" ")[0].strip().upper()) 
         if len(x['Company Name'].split(" ")[0].strip()) <= 4 and x['Company Name'].split(" ")[0].strip().lower() not in dict_words
         else x['Company Name'],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0          Visa Inc
1          Msci Inc
2     Coca Cola Inc
3          PNC Bank
4          AIG Corp
5     TD Ameritrade
6          Uber Inc
7        Costco Inc
8    New York Times
```

Download the nltk package version by runnning:

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

Demo:

```
from nltk.corpus import words

"new" in words.words()
```

Output:

```
 False
```

Comment: Uber is a word though (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/über-)? And why would Costco be capitalized since it's > 4 characters?

Comment: sorry  that was a typo on my part, uber isn't deemed an english word because it's missing the accent above the letter u

Comment: also wordster is a python wrapper for the merriam webster website

from wordster import wordster

# get list of different meanings for a given word
print(wordster.find_meaning("uber"))
Output:
['No result found']

It couldn't find any definitions for uber